# Linking sql tables in table rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am unsure how to ask this, but I will give it my best shot. Currently, I have a few tables which hold indices into other tables to get information. For example, I have a row with name_id as 1, which indicates that I should look at the 'name' table and go to index 1. Is there anyway to directly link a row within a row? Is there another design choice which would be much better than this? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "directly link a row within a row"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use what are called foreign keys, [here](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) is an explanation of them in Sqlite.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is what I was looking for!

Comment: In a similar manner, is there anything that could be done when you have a string that represents another table in the row of a table? I have table A which in its rows has a table B it references to store additional information. Is there something similar to foreign keys that would also work in this instance? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

this is the preferred method of database design

you write a sql statement that uses a JOIN to get the linked rows back.